# jQuery allow to toggle only one element

Tags: jquery

So the code below works only for first element 'GALLERYTITLE',

```
$(function(){$("#diradd").click(function(event)
{event.preventDefault();$("#diraddform").slideToggle();});});
```

HTML:

```
<!--stuff before-->

<div class="gallerytitle"

<a href="#"class="options" id="diradd" >Add new sub-gallery</a> <!--"button"-->

<!--another stuff divs, buttons etc.-->

<div id="diraddform">

<!--things in this div-->
</div></div> <!--the end of #1 gallerytitle div-->

<div class="gallerytitle"

<a href="#"class="options" id="diradd" >Add new sub-gallery</a> <!--"button"-->

<!--another stuff divs, buttons etc.-->

<div id="diraddform">

<!--things in this div-->

</div>

</div> <!--the end of #2 gallerytitle div-->
```

css:

```
diraddform{
display:none;}
```

[basically i have the same probleme like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585521/jquery-only-toggle-one-element-without-having-to-use-ids)

but I can't use .next(); because i have  divs after my "button"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [DEMO](http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp8h)

```
<!--stuff before-->

<div class="gallerytitle">

<a href="#" class="options diradd" >
  Add new sub-gallery
</a>
  <div></div>
<!--"button"-->

  <div>Extra Buttons & Elements</div>

<div class="diraddform">
  zxcczc
</div>
</div>

<!--the end of #1 gallerytitle div-->

<div class="gallerytitle">

  <a href="#" class="options diradd">
    Add new sub-gallery 
  </a>

  <!--"button"-->

  <div>Extra Buttons & Elements</div>

  <div class="diraddform">

    zxczczczc

  </div>

</div>

<!--the end of #2 gallerytitle div-->
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    $(".options").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest(".gallerytitle").find('.diraddform').slideToggle(1000);
    });
});
```

css

```
.diraddform{
display:none;}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer that `id` is unique. I appreciate you for the above solution. But do not misguide OP to use multiple ids(same name) within a page. Thanks!

Comment: @ A.K yes id should be unique. But many things are not proper in above pasted code. like you can see CSS. anyways it would be better if Z373 change it.

Comment: thank you) but I can't use .next(), because after <a href="#" class="options diradd" >Add new sub-gallery</a> i have div's :( and this is my problem(((

Comment: code is updated which takes care of extra divs. Jquery has Cool function called closet you can use that to fins common container and do ops in side that. Also duplicate IDs are removed

Answer (score 3):

The ID must be unique in a document, and is often used to retrieve the element using `document.getElementById` or by using `jQuery Selector`

You have to replace all the **ids** of same name with **class**

I have changed your markup and replace all **ids** with **class**

### HTML:

```
<div class="gallerytitle">
    <a href="#" class="options diradd">Add new sub-gallery</a> 
    <!--"button"-->

    <!--another stuff divs, buttons etc.-->
    <div class="diraddform">
        test1
        <!--things in this div-->
    </div>
</div> 
<!--the end of #1 gallerytitle div-->

<div class="gallerytitle">
    <a href="#" class="options diradd" >Add new sub-gallery</a> 
    <!--"button"-->

    <!--another stuff divs, buttons etc.-->
    <div class="diraddform">
        test 2
        <!--things in this div-->
    </div>
</div>
```

​

### jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $(".diradd").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).next('.diraddform').slideToggle();
    });
});​
```

### [SEE HOW IT IS WORKING HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/gVBQE/)

Comment: thanx) but I can't use .next(), because after   <a href="#" class="options diradd" >Add new sub-gallery</a> i have div's :(

Answer (score 0):

A id is unique, you can't assign it twice (use class).

Answer (score 0):

if you fix the markup with classes you can either use (based on that you use classes insead of div):

```
$(function(){
    $(".options").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().find('.diraddform').slideToggle();
    });
});​
```

Or you want to add more children and have a parent for all your forms+options you could use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest):

```
$(function(){
    $(".options").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('.gallerytitle').find('.diraddform').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ivegat/1/edit or closest: http://jsbin.com/ivegat/4/edit